# IIS Browse link does nothing and 404 error

Tags: iis, iis-7

My client had to reinstall the whole server, so I redeployed my ASP.NET MVC app, but I can't browse it. I deployed successfully with the FTP and the website is in the proper local directory.

When I click the link (on the right panel of IIS) Browse crm on *:80, nothing happens. No error, no IE or Chrome opening, just nothing. I also tried to access the app by typing localhost or localhost/myapp (which should be the right path) directly in the web browser and I got

> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found

.

I did not install the IIS, but I did the configuration. Have I missed something?

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- All the roles previously activated have been activated
- The MVC framework has been installed and SQL also.
- Enabled the IIS tracing and it didn't trace anything

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the application is running under the correct version of .NET.  MVC applications targeting 4.0 running under a 2.0 application pool will return 404.  Make sure the site binding is pointing at the correct directory of the application you just deployed.  When all else fails, try putting a simple .html file into the site and accessing that through the browser.  If that fails, it means that IIS is not set up to serve the site, so check bindings, application pools, and home directories.